# Splash Screen Alpha Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen, thread-sleep

I want to display a splash screen animation where an image fades in and then fades out.  I want the second activity to load after the image has faded out.

1. Fade-in time (1000 ms)
2. Wait (1000 ms)
3. Fade-out time (1000 ms)
4. Wait (1000 ms)
5. Load second Activity

How do I go about this?  The code I'm currently using is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class Splash extends Activity
{
    ImageView img;
    Thread timer;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imgSplash);
        img.startAnimation(FadeIn(1000));
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        img.startAnimation(FadeOut(1000));

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        timer.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(Splash.this,MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
    private Animation FadeIn(int t)
    {
        Animation fade;
        fade = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);
        fade.setDuration(t);
        fade.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return fade;
    }
    private Animation FadeOut(int t)
    {
        Animation fade;
        fade = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
        fade.setDuration(t);
        fade.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return fade;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: The second activity isn't starting? Or are you verifying that it will start?

Comment: 1) Your `timer` is never initialized

Comment: Please do not force your users to wait needlessly for 4 seconds every time they want to use your application. By doing this you are wasting their time (which will annoy them). If you have something that needs to be loaded before your activity can begin then show a splash during the loading. You are just wasting their time by adding arbitrary lag time to the application before they can get to it. [See this article](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) if you are deadset on wasting your users time. It will instruct you how to do so properly.

Comment: 2) The `Thread.sleep()` are executed in the main thread: which blocks the UI ->  that should be done in a separate thread

Comment: Tim - the timing will be changed once i get the animation to work.

Comment: @arnabghosal that doesn't change the fact that any artificially induced lag is wasting their time. If you have loading to do, show a splash while you load, otherwise let them get on with what it is they actually want to do. I promise you that they'll be happier. Either way the article that I linked will show you the proper way to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using an AnimationSet. The `Animation.setStartOffset()` method allows to say when the animation should start (0 for the fadeIn and 2000 for the fadeOut). The next Activity is launched after 3 seconds using a `Handler.postDelayed()`.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable startActivityRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(Splash.this,MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imgSplash);

    setContentView(img);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation fadeIn = FadeIn(1000);
    fadeIn.setStartOffset(0);
    set.addAnimation(fadeIn);

    Animation fadeOut = FadeOut(1000);
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(2000);
    set.addAnimation(fadeOut);

    img.startAnimation(set);

    handler.postDelayed(startActivityRunnable, 3000);
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(startActivityRunnable);
}
```

Comment: Just a mistake in copy/paste...I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: How about this new version ? The 'back' issue should be solved, right ?

Comment: Yes that should do it. Note though I still suggest not to use a splash screen if you have no background work to do.

Comment: @fiddler - thanks for your solution... it works perfectly.. had to make minor changes