# How to move to another activity in a few seconds?

Tags: android, android-activity, timer

I have a splash screen. I just want it to wait for 1 or 2 sec and then move on to the next activity just then once. 
I understand there are many ways including handler classes and java.util.timer implementation. But which is the easiest and most light way to do just this. Thanx in advance.

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455455/splash-screen-alpha-animation-in-android/11456132#11456132

Comment: i am not doing any animations or repeated actions for that matter. Thats why i asked for a much simpler solution. Just to go to the next screen after 2 sec.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use below Code for that.

Splash_Screen_Activity.java

```
public class Splash_Screen_Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // TODO: Your application init goes here.
                Intent mInHome = new Intent(Splash_Screen_Activity.this, InvoiceASAPTabActivity.class);
                Splash_Screen_Activity.this.startActivity(mInHome);
                Splash_Screen_Activity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what i was talking about. Worked like a charm. Thanx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, which includes fade effect.

**res/transition/fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

**res/transition/fade_out.xml**

```
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.transition.fade_in,R.transition.fade_out);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

}
```

For a complete app example **(with more features)**, check [here](https://github.com/ivanlmj/Android-SplashActivity).